# wordpress redirect based on role using login_url hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use [login_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/)
and it works with non-logged in users.
But it doesn't work for logged in users (it redirects them to `/access-denied/` page which is weird), and I really don't know why.

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

function my_login_page( $login_url ) {
    $user = $current_user;
    $valid_roles = [ "administrator", "editor", "custom-role" ];
    $the_roles = array_intersect( $valid_roles, $user->roles );

    if ( empty( $the_roles ) ) {
        return ( "/access-denied/" );
    } else {
        return ( "/login/" );
    }
}
add_filter( "login_url", "my_login_page", 10 );
```

Comment: `$the_roles` would be empty here, if `$user->roles` was either completely empty, or did not contain any of the three roles you have in `$valid_roles`. So go debug and figure out what you are actually dealing with.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I did exactly what you asked and I figured something that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't too hard:

```
$user = $current_user;
$valid_roles = [ 'administrator', 'editor', 'custom-role' ];
$the_roles = array_intersect( $valid_roles, $user->roles );

if ( empty( $the_roles ) ) {
    nocache_headers();
    wp_safe_redirect( '/access-denied/' ); 
    exit;
}
```